# ERROR: What does "use of class template 's_array' requires template arguments" mean?

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

Im currently studying for an exam in c++.

I'm doing some practice questions on templates and have became totally stuck, i'v checked my code and it follows the solutions but this error keeps poping up. I'm unsure how I am passing in the wrong arguements (this is what I believe the issue is.

Code is listed below, any help is greatly appreciated

Tester

```
int main(){

    s_array array(10);
    array[5] = 5; //inbound access
    cout << array[5] << endl;

    array[-1] = 2;
    cout << array[15];
    return 0;
}
```

header, class and templates:

```
template <typename T>
class s_array {
    public:
    s_array(int size);
    ~s_array();

    T &operator[](int i);

    private:
    int size;
    T* data;
};

template <typename T>
s_array<T>::s_array(int size) : size(size)
{
    /*
     * If the size of the array is greater than zero
     * A new array is created at the value of size
     */
    if(size > 0) data = new T[size];
    else{
        std::cout << "Invalid array" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

template <typename T>
s_array<T>::~s_array()
{
    delete [] data;
}
/*
 * Safety feature for the array going out of bounds
 */
template <typename T>
T& s_array<T>::operator[](int i)
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= size){
        std::cout << "index" << i << "is out of bounds" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return data[i];
}
```

Comment: Check again how you are supposed to use a class template where the types can't be deduced from the constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to say what type the `s_array` is holding, for example this would define the array to contain `int` types. In the template definition, `int` will now be substituted everywhere that `T` used to be

```
s_array<int> array(10);
```